# What is the theory behind these current equations? (for Z paramaters)

Tags: passive-networks, network, s-parameters, equation

In the photo below is shown the method for deriving z-parameters of the circuit. Apologies for my badly drawn values for resistors as they weren't shown in the original image. Basically I'm struggling to see where the parts in red circles are coming from. I understand each of the Z equations but I don't know the actual theory behind those identities for Io and Io'.

The Io identity applies when I2 is 0. I can't tell if the 1/2 in the identity is actually a half, or if its the resistor values(there is a 1 and a 2 ohm resistor in the circuit). The reason this confuses me is because I'm doing this with a similar circuit which doesn't have that 1ohm resistor, but does have the other 3, so I need to know if the identity would be different for my circuit.

The Io' identity applies when I1 is 0. It seems like it is 2/(2+4+6) but again I'm not sure why.

So can anyone tell me whats the name of the rule that would provide an explanation for the circled identities, and help me understand why they apply when I1 and I2 equal 0.

Sorry if I haven't explained this well I'm having difficulty putting it into words, so if you're confused I'll happily clear up anything you need!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The Io identity applies when I2 is 0.*

Just think about how the \$I_1\$ current shares itself out. The 1 ohm resistor is irrelevant and so \$I_1\$ flows into two parallel resistors of which one is 6 ohm and the other is a series connected 4 ohm and 2 ohm. That series resistance is also 6 ohm hence the current shares equally: -

$$I_0 = \dfrac{1}{2} I_1$$

> *The reason this confuses me is because I'm doing this with a similar
>   circuit which doesn't have that 1ohm resistor, but does have the other
>   3, so I need to know if the identity would be different for my
>   circuit.*

The 1 ohm is irrelevant when connected in series with a current source.

In the second circuit \$I_2\$ (from the voltage source on the right) flows into a 2 ohm load in parallel with a 10 ohm (4 plus 6 in series) load. The far left 1 ohm resistor is now regarded as open circuit because it was in series with a current source.

Can you see now how \$I_0'\$ is formed from your second equation inside the red box?

Comment: I think I understand, those are just current dividers right? So, ignoring the 1ohm resistor, we have one divider where I2=0 using a 6ohm in parallel with 6ohm, and another divider where I1=0 using a 10ohm in parallel with a 2ohm?

Comment: And the half has come from 6/(6+6)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Great thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I've redrawn your first circuit to make it more clear what's going on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvqk2f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The amount of current which flows through \$R_4\$ is equal to the amount of current which flows through \$R_3\$ (by Kirchkoff's current law). Setting up Kirchhoff's current law for \$V_3\$,
$$
I_0 + I_{R_2} = I_1
$$
Substituting in from Ohm's law,
$$
\frac{V_3}{R_3 + R_4} + \frac{V_3}{R_2} = I_1\\
V_3 \left(\frac{1}{R_3 + R_4} + \frac{1}{R_2}\right) = I_1\\
V_3 = \frac{I_1}{\left(\frac{1}{R_3 + R_4} + \frac{1}{R_2}\right)}
$$
Plugging in numbers for the resistors,
$$
V_3 = \frac{I_1}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}} = 3 I_1\\
(R_3 + R_4) I_0 = V_3\\
I_0 = \frac{3 I_1}{6} = \frac{I_1}{2}
$$